# Awesome Effect on Ripple XRP Website

Tags: ripple, cryptocurrency

I recently decided to check the new website for the Ripple (XRP) cryptocurrency and as a web developer, the showcase blew my mind. Can someone explain to me how this is possible and how can I replicate this effect. Thanks!

https://ripple.com/xrp/

Comment: Have a look at the source code, I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [google.com](http://www.google.com). DYOR first my friend.

Have a look at [this](https://codepen.io/ElenaDroueva/pen/OVdvdp).
Looks like a pure css implementation

```
perspective: 1px;
transform: translateZ(-1px) scale(2);
```

being your key words.